# Flutter MouseRegion Hover Pauses Temporarily While Scrolling, Causing projects button to stop tracking mouse movements

Tags: flutter, animation, hover

I'm encountering an issue in my Flutter application where the hover effect within a MouseRegion is interrupted when scrolling begins. This interruption causes Project button to stop tracking mouse movements.

Here's a GIF illustrating the problem:
[Flutter MouseRegion Hover Interruption During Scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWqPR.gif)

I've attempted adjusting the MouseRegion properties in Flutter to mitigate the hovering interruption during scrolling. However, despite these tweaks, the issue persists, causing the Projects button functionality to pause unexpectedly.

Here's the code snippet:

```
class MainButtonStarting extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainButtonStarting({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainButtonStarting> createState() => _MainButtonStartingState();
}

class _MainButtonStartingState extends State<MainButtonStarting>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  var containerPosition = const Offset(
    10000,
    680,
  );

  double containerSize = 100;
  double containerOpacity = .5;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      containerPosition = Offset(
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 410,
        670,
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MouseRegion(
      onExit: (event) {
        containerOpacity = .5;

        containerPosition = Offset(
          MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 410,
          670,
        );
        containerSize = 100;
      },
      onHover: (event) {
        setState(() {
          containerOpacity = 1;

          containerSize = 156;
          double containerWidth =
              100; // Adjust according to your container size
          double containerHeight =
              100; // Adjust according to your container size
          double mouseX = event.localPosition.dx;
          double mouseY = event.localPosition.dy;
          double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
          double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

          // Calculate new position for the container
          double newLeft = mouseX - containerSize / 2;
          double newTop = mouseY - containerSize / 2;

          // Ensure the container stays within the bounds of the screen
          if (newLeft < 0) {
            newLeft = 0;
          } else if (newLeft + containerWidth > screenWidth) {
            newLeft = screenWidth - containerWidth;
          }

          if (newTop < 0) {
            newTop = 0;
          } else if (newTop + containerHeight > screenHeight) {
            newTop = screenHeight - containerHeight;
          }

          // Update container position
          containerPosition = Offset(newLeft, newTop);
        });
      },
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 782,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: basicContainer,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/newImages/bg_container.png',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    height: 782,
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 50,
                  bottom: 40,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 875,
                    decoration: basicContainer,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(46.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 875,
                            child: Text(
                              'Embracing the interplay of artistic freedom and strategic order.',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                              style: GoogleFonts.gfsDidot(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 40,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const Gap(74),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 537,
                                child: Text(
                                  'We welcome the invigorating fusion of boundless creativity and steadfast structure. It’s within this captivating balance that we discover our inspiration and drive to deliver exceptional results.\n\nOur design philosophy is rooted in our commitment to creativity, collaboration, and attention to detail. \n\nWe are committed to delivering the best possible design solutions that works for you.',
                                  style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: 163,
                                height: 55,
                                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                                decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    side: const BorderSide(
                                        width: 1, color: Color(0xFF6C6C6C)),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                child: const Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'About us',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      fontFamily: 'Inter',
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          AnimatedPositioned(
            curve: Curves.fastEaseInToSlowEaseOut,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
            left: containerPosition.dx,
            top: containerPosition.dy,
            child: AnimatedOpacity(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
              opacity: containerOpacity,
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                width: containerSize,
                height: containerSize,
                decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                  color: Color(0x7F6C6C6C),
                  shape: OvalBorder(
                    side: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Projects',
                    style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting problem, what occurs to me is to wrap the mouseregion inside a listener that detects the scroll and corrects the position. I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but I can't think of anything better. Look, an example would be as follows, but of course, implement the calculation as appropriate, taking into account everything that may influence.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      onPointerSignal: (pointerSignal) {
        if (pointerSignal is PointerScrollEvent) {
          final scrollMoved = pointerSignal.scrollDelta.dy;
          setState(() {
            containerPosition = Offset(
                //move position on Y
                containerPosition.dx, containerPosition.dy + scrollMoved);
          });
        }
      },
      child: MouseRegion(
        onExit: (event) {
          containerOpacity = .5;
...
```